# Why is my web page being reloaded when trying to read data from firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently having an error where whenever I try to read my data, all it does is reload the page.

```js
const dbRef = ref(getDatabase())

get(child(dbRef, Lusername.value))
    .then((snapshot) =>{
      data = snapshot.val();
      console.log(data)

      //compare inputted data to db data
      if(Lpassword === data.Password){
        window.location.assign("home.html")
      }
      else{
        console.log("Not Working")
      }
```

What I am trying to do is get data from the database. I have the user input a username, ("Lusername), then I compare "Lpassword"(which is the password the user tried to login with) to the Password in the database under the inputted username, and if they compare correctly it will take you to the home page. If not, it will console log. But for some reason, instead of console logging or taking me to the home page, (side note: the password and username i am inputting is stored in the database currently.) it just reloads the page.

Comment: *The `Location.assign()` method causes the window to load and display the document at the URL specified. After the navigation occurs, the user can navigate back to the page that called `Location.assign()` by pressing the "back" button.* From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign).

Comment: @LightningMcQueen, yes i know that. But i am currently on the "login.html" page. I want to redirect to "home.html" if it is valid. But all it does is reload.

Comment: Instead of using `window.location.assign("home.html")`, try `console.log("Anything here!")` to see whatever `Lpassword === data.Password` for debugging purposes. If it still redirects, then the problem is somewhere else. Nothing else in your code (the code you posted) could force a redirect.

Comment: On a side note, receiving a plain password, and comparing it isn't really secure (from my very personal point of view), that's why Firebase Authentication was made in the first place. In this case, you might want to use [`reauthenticateWithCredential()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) method.

Comment: For some reason it still reloads. I have scanned the entire code and there is no reason for a reload.

Comment: Then I'm afraid that your question might get closed as "Needs details or clarity" because I (and no one) will be able to debug your issue. The code you posted doesn't force reload anywhere after you removed `window.location.assign("home.html")` - happy to corrected in case I'm wrong.

Comment: Are you clearing your browser cache when you make changes?

Comment: No, i found the issue. in the html, i had a submit button